# Dropping files or opening files from the file selector dialog box causes the React component to unmount

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component form that has text fields and the react dropzone. When I update the text fields, the component does not unmount, but when I drop files in by dragging into the dropzone area or open file dialog and select files, the component unmounts. I use React's useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(onDropProp) {
    onDropProp();
  }

  let message = snackBarMessage;
  if(droppedFileObjects.length > 0) {
    setFileObjects([...fileObjects, ...droppedFileObjects]);
    droppedFileObjects.forEach(f => message += `File ${f.file.name} successfully added. `);
  }

  setSnackBarMessage(message);          
  if(message !== '') { 
    setOpenSnackBar(true);
    setSnackBarVariant('success');
  }

  //unmount
  return () => {
    if(clearOnUnmount) {
      console.log('Unmounted: droppedfileobject effect called');
    }
  };
}, 
[droppedFileObjects]);
```

When i open the file dialog in the react dropzone component and select a file or drag and drop the file in, it calls the section of code with a comment that says "unmount". I would not expect this behavior, unless I actually unload the component i.e. screen goes away, that the useEffect sits in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanup callback for an effect hook is called **when any of the dependencies change**, as well as on unmount. (The dependencies are the array passed as the second parameter to `useEffect`.) So in this case, the component probably isn't unmounting, it's just cleaning up and re-running the effect function because `droppedFileObjects` changed.

To help understand how the `useEffect` hook works, I'd recommend reading through the page about it in the React docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you @ecraig12345, I read the document again, and found that I needed to use the useEffect with the empty array in the dependencies argument. I also used the ref to the state, so that I get the most updated state at unmount. Thanks for the help.